# Comparing 2 Image's sources in Javascript

Tags: javascript, comparison-operators

I'm trying to compare 2 images to see if they're the same. I've done quite a bit of research on this and can't come to a working conclusion. Here is an example of what I have now:

```
var image1 = document.getElementById('imgId1');
var image2 = document.getElementById('imgId2');
if(image1.src.match(image2.src)) {   <---This seems to only work w/ a string

  //do whatever here
}
```

I've also tried other things such as:

```
if(image2.src.indexOf(image1.src)!= -1)
{
    //do whatever here
}
```

and

```
if(image2.src == image1.src)
{

}
```

and

```
if(image2.src === image1.src)
{

}
```

I've tried using single quotes, double quotes, no quotes.. I haven't taken a Javascript class before so this kind of comparison is new to me. Any help would be great, thanks.

FULL CODE --

```
<script language="javascript">

function changeImage1() {

    var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 48) + 1);
    var n = num.toString();
    var numImg = n.concat(".jpeg");
    var string = "/blah/blah/"
    var final = string.concat(numImg);
    var image = document.getElementById('imgClickAndChange1');
    var image2 = document.getElementById('imgClickAndChange2');
    if(image.src.match("blah.jpg")) {
        var num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 48) + 1);
        var n2 = num2.toString();
        var numImg2 = n2.concat(".jpeg");
        var final2 = string.concat(numImg2);
        image2.src = final2;
        image.src = final;
        if(image2.src == image.src){
            num2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 48) + 1);
            n2 = num2.toString();
            numImg2 = n2.concat(".jpeg");
            final2 = string.concat(numImg2);
            image2.src = final2;
        }
    } else {
        image.src = final;
        if(image.src == image2.src){
            num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 48) + 1);
            n = num.toString();
            numImg = n.concat(".jpeg");
            final = string.concat(numImg);
            image.src = final;
        }

    }
}
```

I realize that there is still a slight chance the images will be the same after the 2nd rand. -- Script will still put images as the same in the 1st pass

Comment: If they don't match using `==`, then they just don't match. Have you logged both values of `.src` to the console to see what they actually are? What do the sources in the HTML start out as?

Comment: Is there a problem with any of the attempts you tried? Not quite sure what your question is. `===` is the way to test primitive values for equality. If you are not very familiar with JavaScript, why don't you read a tutorial? http://eloquentjavascript.net/ *"I've tried using single quotes, double quotes, no quotes."* Quotation marks denote a string literal for the *parser*. They are not part of the value, so it's irrelevant which one you use.

Comment: @squint @FelixKling    --- The use for this is to make sure 2 of the same images don't pop up at the same time. If they are the same, one will change to a different image. I know it's not working because 2 images will still pop up and be the same. The sources in the HTML start out like so: `<img alt="" src="blah.jpg" style="height: 276px; width: 200px" id="imgClickAndChange1" onclick="changeImage2()" />`

Comment: *"I know it's not working because 2 images will still pop up and be the same."* Equality of strings is pretty simple. Either the characters in the strings are `==` or they're not. You need to give a working demonstration of the issue. Whatever problem your code has, it isn't represented in your question and so makes it unanswerable except to tell you that `==` works even though it seems to fail for you, which isn't terribly helpful for your situation.

Comment: @squint There's really no other way to describe it. -- Check the new information. When one image is clicked the other image will be changed. If the new image being changed is the same as the other image it will give a new image to the src.

Comment: First thing is to do some debugging by logging your values to the console as I mentioned in my first comment. `console.log(image1.src)` will give you lots of information. Even though the `src` starts out as `"blah.jpg"` it's probably ending up as `"http://your_domain/blah.jpg"`. Use `image1.getAttribute("src")` to get the original attribute value.

Comment: ...also, it looks like you're probably duplicating that function. A better way is to make a single function and pass the clicked image into it. `<img ... id="imgClickAndChange1" onclick="changeImage(this)" />`. Notice I changed the call to `"changeImage(this)"`. So then define a parameter `image` to your function, and that'll be the clicked image. Because you don't know *which* image it will be, you can compare its `.id`. If it was `"imgClickAndChange1"`, then the other image is `"imgClickAndChange2"`, and vice versa.

Comment: ...and don't use `.match()` here. Use `===`.

Comment: When you are using `onclick="changeImage(this)"` will your function look like so: `function changeImage(image){   if(image.id == imgClickAndChange1){  //do smething } else{ //do something} }`  From there are you able to reference the image source? Like `image.src = var;`?

Comment: I am having a similar issue, however it cannot be resolved with the answer below, please look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65219491/compare-duplicates-of-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The double equals '==' should be fine. Try outputting the values when it fails to see what's up.

```
if(image2.src == image1.src)
{

}
else
{
    console.log([image2.src, image1.src]);
    alert("They did not match because 1 is " + image1.src + " and 2 is " + image2.src);
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @LawrenceAiello of course it did. It told him the correct way to compare strings which is what he wanted. The rest is just the added benefit of knowing how to debug when your code doesn't show what you expected.